# Unescape confirmation dialog text

Tags: oracle-apex

I have Dynamic Action "Confirm" with text from page item (&P1_MESSAGE.). Problem is that text from page item is escaped, how I can unescape it? For example page item text is `... <b>...</b> ...<br><br>...`, confirm dialog displays this text with html tags.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to disable this option in the attributes of your Page Item ?

**Security > Escape special characters**

[image: unescape special character]

Comment: As far as I can tell, that property is NOT available for page items. It is for e.g. report columns. Can you prove me wrong, please?

Comment: Yes, for page item is not available.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry then, I thought it was possible